# Accessing Angular4 Router Data Property

Tags: angular, angular4-router

I'm trying to get my head around the Angular4 world.

What I'm trying to do. I'm using Material2 and Flex and I want to pass with each route, if the sidebar should be open or closed when the route changes. I thought passing this with the `data`option was a viable option.

The `AppComponent` holds the logic for this globally.

I have defined my routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    data: { showMenuDefault: true }
  }
]
```

And now I'm tring to access the `data` attributes in the object.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { MenuRoutes } from './app.routes';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {

  opened;
  menuRoutes;

  constructor(private router:Router, private activeRoute:ActivatedRoute) {
    this.menuRoutes = MenuRoutes;
    this.opened = this.activeRoute.snapshot.data.showMenuDefault;
    console.log(this.opened)
  }

}
```

I always get `undefined`. Could someone please hint me in the right direction?

Comment: but that's a data for the `HomeComponent`, why are trying to access it in the `AppComponent `?

Comment: are you navigating from your home component to app component and passing this data ?

Comment: I've parked the logic in the AppComponent. This way I thought the logic is global ...

Comment: @Tino, no, you can get a data inside the `HomeComponent` when you navigate to `/home`

Comment: If you want data available globally, consider building a service instead. Unless of course the value is different for different routes.